# Rails 7 + Turbo: Turbo navigates away when receiving 422 unprocessable entity

Tags: forms, http, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo, rails7

According to various sources, the way to fail form validation in Rails 7 is to respond with status 422 unprocessable entity. However, in my case, this causes Turbo to issue yet another GET request, which is unlikely to be the desired outcome.

The log looks as follows:

```
Started POST "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-06-16 17:27:48 +0200
...
TRANSACTION (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
...
Rendered html template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 133ms (Views: 1.2ms | ActiveRecord: 10.9ms | Allocations: 54437)

Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-06-16 17:27:48 +0200
...
```

So, from a Rails perspective, everything seems normal, as the server responds with the required 422 status code. When inspecting the response in the browser, I see the form with the error messages. However, for some reason, Turbo then issues a redirect to `/users/new` instead of letting the browser display the form containing the errors.

UPDATE: The form is generated using `simple_form_for`.

How can I find out why Turbo reloads the page?

Best,
Kalsan

Comment: Hi @Kalsan - did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Are you also affected by this? I've been feeling like I'm the only person on earch/Google to have this problem for the last 2 weeks...

Comment: This was a frustrating problem – I'm glad I wasn't the only one ;)  For me the cause turned out to be using the wrong layout in my 422 response (see @dougjq's answer below).

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the server responds with a partial to a form post. Returning a complete site, including `<html>` etc. solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Far from a Rails expert here, but I have seen a Turbo form submit, get a response of 422 :unprocessable_entity and then immediately GET the starting url with response 200. It's maddeningly undocumented afaik. I've asked for official documentation help here:

https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/do-we-need-official-rails-7-guides-for-integrating-with-turbo-to-counter-stackoverflow-cruft/83635

It happens when Turbo cannot find a complete DOM in the response. It can't compare what you have to what you're getting and so it just stomps the 422 and GETs. I have seen this happen in two circumstances: rendering a partial instead of rendering a complete response, or rendering from a controller without a layout.

## Cause 1: Rendering a partial instead of fully rendering

The following will result in a surprise GET 200 that stomps your 422 unprocessable_entity:

```
# with app/views/_book.html.haml
render partial: 'book'
return
```

```
render partial: 'book', status: :unprocessable_entity
return
```

Surprise! You would think the magic of Turbo would be able to neatly identify your partial for replacement, but it cannot. You'd think it would raise an exception, but it does not.

This on the other hand will work:

```
# app/views/book.html.haml
render 'book', status: :unprocessable_entity
```

Now you're calling for a complete response and the 422 sticks.

Documentation describing `render` as a complete response:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#creating-responses

## Cause 2: Using a controller without a layout

There's a method for selecting your layout and Rails can select no layout or the wrong layout, apparently.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts

This could be wrong if you don't have a "more_different_book" layout:

```
# controllers/more_different_book_controller.rb
# no layout called for
def do_stuff
  ...
  return render 'book', status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

GET 200!

But adding an explicit (existing) layout could magically fix it:

```
# controllers/more_different_book_controller.rb
layout 'book'
def do_stuff
  ...
  return render 'book', status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

I could be misunderstanding the cause, but this is what I have observed and how I moved past it.